# mudblazor tree how to add delete nodes

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am implementing a project that will use MudBlazor TreeView, and understand how to implement the C# tree, but am not sure how I can add or delete selected nodes and update the treeview accordingly. Note this is not about server side CRUD, rather just updating the tree that is displayed with new or deleted nodes in the tree. i.e I would like to select a node and just delete it from the view, or add a new node into the tree and display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add and remove items to/from the items collection of a treeview in MudBlazor. I transformed one of the examples at https://mudblazor.com/components/treeview into a little demo for you with which you can play around online: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cuwlvFQcfJTzHuki

Here is the full code for the example. It adds corona virus nodes to a treeview when you click the add button and removes them one by one when you click the delete button:

```html
<MudButton OnClick="AddItems" Variant="Variant.Filled">Add items</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="DeleteItems" Variant="Variant.Filled">Delete items</MudButton>

<MudPaper Width="300px" Elevation="0">
    <MudTreeView Items="TreeItems" MultiSelection="true" @bind-ActivatedValue="ActivatedValue" @bind-SelectedValues="SelectedValues">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <MudTreeViewItem @bind-Expanded="@context.IsExpanded" Items="@context.TreeItems" Value="@context"
                             Icon="@context.Icon" Text="@context.Title" EndText="@context.Number?.ToString()" EndTextTypo="@Typo.caption" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </MudTreeView>
</MudPaper>

<div style="width: 100%">
    <MudText Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Activated item: @(ActivatedValue?.Title)</MudText>
    <MudText Typo="@Typo.subtitle1">Sum of selected items: @GetSelectedSum()</MudText>
</div>

@code {
    private TreeItemData ActivatedValue { get; set; }

    private HashSet<TreeItemData> SelectedValues { get; set; }

    private HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<TreeItemData>();

    public class TreeItemData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }

        public int? Number { get; set; }

        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

        public HashSet<TreeItemData> TreeItems { get; set; }

        public TreeItemData(string title, string icon, int? number = null)
        {
            Title = title;
            Icon = icon;
            Number = number;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object x) {
            var other = x as TreeItemData;
            if (other==null)
                return false;
            return other.Title==Title;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return Title.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("All Mail", Icons.Filled.Email));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Trash", Icons.Filled.Delete));
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Categories", Icons.Filled.Label)
        {
            IsExpanded = true,
            TreeItems = new HashSet<TreeItemData>()
            {
                new TreeItemData("Social", Icons.Filled.Group, 90),
                new TreeItemData("Updates", Icons.Filled.Info, 2294),
                new TreeItemData("Forums", Icons.Filled.QuestionAnswer, 3566),
                new TreeItemData("Promotions", Icons.Filled.LocalOffer, 733)
            }
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("History", Icons.Filled.Label));
    }

    public int GetSelectedSum()
    {
        return SelectedValues?.Sum(i => i.Number ?? 0) ?? 0;
    }

    private int i=0;

    public void AddItems() {
        TreeItems.Add(new TreeItemData("Added Item " + (i++), Icons.Filled.Coronavirus));
    }

    public void DeleteItems() {
        var item=TreeItems.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Title.StartsWith("Added Item"));
        TreeItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Note: make sure your model overrides `Equals` and `GetHashcode` like I showed in the example!